# Compile ffmpeg library statically using visual c++

Tags: c, visual-c++, ffmpeg, static-libraries

When I try to compile ffmpeg library statically using visual studio 2015, with following configure options

```
 ./configure --toolchain=msvc --arch=x86 --enable-yasm --enable-asm  --disable-shared --enable-static
```

surprisingly, I get `.a` libraries instead of `.lib`. How can I compile ffmpeg to generate .libs ?